# How to define a higher-degree spline using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, spline

I am using the Scipy [CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html) interpolation based on a certain number of points as shown in the diagram below:[image: Scipy Cubic Spline]

My problem is, the second derivative of the Cubic Splive function looks a little bit edgy:

[image: Second derivative]

In order to smooth the second curve I need a higher degree of spline interpolation. Is there a Scipy build in function (similar to CubicSpline) or an easy way to do that? (A b-spline function want work)

Comment: have a look at [UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline), the degree could be set up to 5

Comment: Expecting derivatives of a spline to look smooth ignores the fact that splines are defined in a piecewise manner.

Comment: What do you mean?  Is there a better way to achieve a smooth derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_interp_spline` should be able to construct BSpline objects of higher degrees (FITPACK only goes up to k=5, which is hardcoded fairly deep down).